# Print Dashboard menu name and link

Tags: functions, admin-menu

I am trying to display the Dashboard's menu by showing the name and the filename associated to it like so:

```
Dashboard > index.php
Posts > edit.php
Media > upload.php
etc...
```

This is what I have so far with using the global `$menu` to show all of the available menu items on the Dashboard:

```
global $menu;
foreach ( $menu as $group => $item ) {
    foreach ( $item as $label ) {
        echo $label . " > " . $item[2] . "<br>";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

However, it gives the following result:

```
Dashboard > index.php
read > index.php
index.php > index.php
> index.php
menu-top menu-top-first menu-icon-dashboard menu-top-last > index.php
menu-dashboard > index.php
dashicons-dashboard > index.php

> separator1
read > separator1
separator1 > separator1
> separator1
wp-menu-separator > separator1

Posts > edit.php
edit_posts > edit.php
edit.php > edit.php
> edit.php
menu-top menu-icon-post open-if-no-js menu-top-first > edit.php
menu-posts > edit.php
dashicons-admin-post > edit.php

etc...
```

I see that I am able to get `Dashboard > index.php` to show, but then there is extra information that I do not need. Any recommendation on what I need to change to just display the first two items of each menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish precisely, since you don't cover that part.

Looking at the data I would guess you can filter out separators and such by checking for proper title:

```
global $menu;
foreach ( $menu as $group => $item ) {

    if ( ! empty( $item[0] ) ) {
        echo $item[0] . " > " . $item[2] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Results for me in:

```
Dashboard > index.php
Posts > edit.php
Media > upload.php
Pages > edit.php?post_type=page
Comments 0 > edit-comments.php
Test > edit.php?post_type=test
Appearance > themes.php
Plugins 0 > plugins.php
Users > users.php
Tools > tools.php
Settings > options-general.php
SEO 00 notifications > wpseo_dashboard
```

Comment: Thank you [Rarst](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/847/rarst), the purpose is to display all of the menu items as checkboxes in my plugin settings. I was testing out the results by printing them to make sure I got the logic down.