# Print Dashboard submenu name and filename

Tags: plugin-development, functions, admin-menu, sub-menu

Similar to [my previous question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/236111/), I want to print a list of all of the submenu items in the *Dashboard* like so:

- **Updates** > update-core.php
- **Library** > upload.php
- **Add New** > media-new.php
- *etc...*

This is what I have so far:

```
global $submenu;
foreach ( $submenu as $group => $item ) {
    echo '<pre>'; print_r( $item ); echo '</pre>';
}
// echo '<pre>'; print_r( $submenu ); echo '</pre>';
```

#### Output

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [0] => Home
            [1] => read
            [2] => index.php
        )

    [10] => Array (
            [0] => Updates 4
            [1] => update_core
            [2] => update-core.php
        )

)
Array (
    [5] => Array (
            [0] => Library
            [1] => upload_files
            [2] => upload.php
        )

    [10] => Array (
            [0] => Add New
            [1] => upload_files
            [2] => media-new.php
        )

)
AND SO ON...
```

I know it's a matter of playing around with the `foreach` and using the right index like [my previous question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/236111/), but I am having trouble with it. Any help and guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want them in an unordered list:

```
echo "<ul>\r\n";
foreach ( $submenu as $group => $item ) {
    foreach ( $submenu[$group] as $key => $value ) {
        echo "<li>" . $submenu[$group][$key][0] . " > " . $submenu[$group][$key][2] . "</li>\r\n";
    }
}
echo "</ul>";
```

This results in:

```
<ul>
<li>Home > index.php</li>
<li>Updates > update-core.php</li>
<li>Library > upload.php</li>
<li>Add New > media-new.php</li>
</ul>
```